# Tags option not selected when editing tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits

One of there options is highlighted pretty much at all time depending what you are doing on Stack Overflow.

[image]

These categories seems to be following these rules (Let's take questions) :

- You interact with a question
- You edit a question

The question is selected.

It seems like the programmers forgot to select it when you are editing a tag. It should follow the same rules.

If I click there :

[image]

Nothing is selected above (the "tags" option should be) :

[image]

Yes, this is a small detail but it's **killing**
 my OCD.

Comment: @Oded it seems like it's completely broken on FireFox 21.0 then. It highlights the category i'm in. Always. So much that I thought it was a feature.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Yes that's what it should be.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Totally right. I forgot to write that. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed and will be out in `rev. 1910` (meta) `rev. 1341` (network).

Comment: I thought you guys forgot about this. Thanks :'(